# Connection timed out while using scp2 nodeJs.

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running the following code:

```
var sendFile = function(){
console.log("sending file to the server")
client.scp(configs.fileName, {
    host: configs.hostName,
    username: configs.userName,
    port : 22,
    password: configs.passWord,
    path: configs.seam_dir,
passphrase: configs.ssh_passphrase,
privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync(configs.ssh_key_filePath)
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
})
}
```

this will give the error:

```
{ [Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake] level: 'connection-timeout' }
```

Note: configs is where i have all the values.

Comment: try `privateKey: String(require('fs').readFileSync(configs.ssh_key_filePath))`; by default fs returns a Buffer, not a string which might be expected by the scp lib. that, or check your values...

Comment: Thnsk dandavis this helped. But still i will get a timeout error for the first time, but when i run it again it works fine. Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: @dandavis still it gives the same error.